# Сайт на html и php с кодированием и декодированием в base64

Tags: php, html, base64, криптография, decrypt

Мне нужно, чтобы после ввода в поле информация отправлялась в php и выполнялся кодирование/декодирование в base64 и возвращало в другое многострочное поле. Как это реализовать? Буду рад исходнику.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: А мы были бы рады для начала вашему коду

Comment: @axmed2004 у меня его нет. Не могли бы вы дать мне пример сайта?

Comment: и как вы собираетесь на каком-то сайте увидеть php код?

Answer (score 0):

Общая элементарная логика - на странице в самом коде две формы. Одна из форм выводится по условию, если был передан `$_POST['data']` из первой формы. В первой форме, соответственно, одни из полей текстовых имеет имя `data`, а сама форма отправляется методом `POST`. Форму отправляете на ту же страницу. Во второй форме (которая отображается по условию) проводите кодирование\декодирование строки и выводите в текстовом поле.